# How do I retrieve inner join column values from database, store them inside an array and return to the calling code in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if I've two models.

`Modela :has_many :modelbs`

`Modelb :belongs_to :modala`

How can I use inner join to retrieve the data from the database, store them inside an array an return it back to the caller as a JSON string?

I understand there are `find` and related methods, but these methods seemed to be returning me array containing only objects of the class I did a find on (eg. `Modela.find`), and I will have to iterate through that array and and pull out Modelbs that belongs to Modela. Is there a easier way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `has_many :posts`

Post `belongs_to :user`

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@posts = @user.posts.to_json
```

**update** Multiple users and their posts to json:

```
@users = User.all
@posts = @users.to_json(:include => :posts)
```

Comment: thanks @bricker. how about if i want to retrieve multiple users and their posts and convert this result into json? is that possible?